# Is there a way to record and replay coding in visual studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-macros

I'm going to do demo based presentation. So what I want is prerecord(not a video record) my demo and replay while the I'm doing the presentation. Pre-record and play as in save code segments and generated some kind of list and then when I click on the list item generate relevant code and insert into code editor. Is there any macro base or any other way to do this?

Please do ask question if this is not clear.

**Update 1**

@jerek has answered the initial question. Going forward is there anyway to replace/edit existing code?

Comment: you mean code snippets? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx

Comment: Something like that, but we can't keep a list of code snippets isn't it? I'm expecting something like solution explorer to keep steps and when I click on the list item it should generate the code.

Answer (score 8):

1. Open Toolbox (View | Toolbox)
2. Select code from editor
3. Drag and Drop into Toolbox (you can give it a short name from context menu)
4. When needed drag and drop back from Toolbox back to code editor

[image]

PS: 3b - instead of drag and drop you can also paste code from clipboard using context menu on Toolbox window

Comment: Thanks Jarek, this is what I exactly wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The [Undo and Redo stack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/04/11/using-the-undo-and-redo-stack-vstipedit0045.aspx) buttons are really useful. They might be enough for what you want to do (basically `CTRL-Z` and `CTRL-SHIFT-Z` but you can roll forward over multiple redo's)

This might be a bit basic, but essentially will allow you to go forwards and backwards through your edits.

Comment: Yes, that is a one option. It's a kind of big demo. So keeping all the things in track is big deal. :)

Answer (score 0):

With Visual Studio, you can code everything and then undo and redo your work. Then record everything with one of [these](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-free-screen-recording-softwares-for-creating-attractive-screencasts/).

Comment: I don't want record and play a video :), See the Jerek's answer. Thanks for answer though.